# Create a combined Landsat and Sentinel mosaic using SEPAL

Tags: sepal

I'm new to the [SEPAL](https://sepal.io) platform and I cannot find lot of information on the web so far.

[image]

I would like to create a Landsat and Sentinel based mosaic on a AOI that I stored as an asset in GEE : `users/bornToBeAlive/aoi_sandan`

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SEPAL you can create a combined Landsat and Sentinel mosaic by using one of the default recipes in the process tab, the cookbook would be the following:

1. Click over process tab and then "Optical Mosaic"
2. Use the AOI button and select "EE Table option" and enter your asset name: `users/bornToBeAlive/aoi_sandan`, make sure that the asset belongs to the GEE account that you have linked to SEPAL or if you are using a third-party asset, it should be [shared as public](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/asset_manager#sharing-assets). Select Column and asset of the interested feature.
3. Click over "DAT" button and select the year for the imagery.
4. In the "SRC" button you'll be able to select the sources to create the mosaic, select your desired Landast satellite and click over Sentinel button.
5. After that you're done and the mosaic will be displayed on the black map.

[image]